# Using os.forkpty() to create a pseudo-terminal to ssh to a remote server and communicate with it

Tags: python, ssh, terminal, fork

I'm trying to write a python script that can ssh into remote server and can execute simple commands like ls,cd from the python client. However, I'm not able to read the output from the pseudo-terminal after successfully ssh'ing into the server. Could anyone please help me here so that I could execute some commands on the server.

Here is the sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
import os,sys,time,thread
pid,fd = os.forkpty()
if pid == 0:
    os.execv('/usr/bin/ssh',['/usr/bin/ssh','user@host',])
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    output = os.read(fd,1024)
    print output
    data = output
    os.write(fd,'password\n')
    time.sleep(1)
    output = os.read(fd,1024)
    print output
    os.write(fd,'ls\n')
    output = os.read(fd,1024)
    print output
```

Sample output:

```
user@host's password: 

Last login: Wed Aug 24 03:16:57 2011 from 1x.x.x.xxxx

-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
host: /home/user>ls
```

Comment: What you try to do here would better be done with public keys, at least the password part.

Comment: I'm guessing you've not heard of [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.1/index.html)?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest trying the module pexpect, which is built exactly for this sort of thing (interfacing with other applications via pseudo-TTYs), or Fabric, which is built for this sort of thing more abstractly (automating system administration tasks on remote servers using SSH).

pexpect: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/

Fabric: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.11/

Answer (score 2):

As already stated, better use public keys. As I use them normally, I have changed your program so that it works here.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
import os,sys,time,thread
pid,fd = os.forkpty()
if pid == 0:
    os.execv('/usr/bin/ssh',['/usr/bin/ssh','localhost',])
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    output = os.read(fd,1024)
    print output
    os.write(fd,'ls\n')
    time.sleep(1) # this is new!
    output = os.read(fd,1024)
    print output
```

With the added `sleep(1)`, I give the remote host (or, in my case, not-so-remote host) time to process the `ls` command and produce its output.

If you send `ls` and read immediately, you only read what is currently present. Maybe you should read in a loop or so.

Or you just should do it this way:

```
import subprocess
sp = subprocess.Popen(("ssh", "localhost", "ls"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print sp.stdout.read()
```

Comment: >> If you send ls and read immediately, you only read what is currently present. Maybe you should read in a loop or so.

Comment: thanks glglgl
but when reading in a continuous loop , the process gets stuck at os.read
snippet from the code

output = os.read(fd,1)
    while  output :
        output = os.read(fd,1)  #it seems to keep waiting

Comment: This is another question. Try to set the fd to nonblocking, maybe that helps. Or use `select()`.